# How to make subdomain from ip using a php form

Tags: ip, subdomain

I want to have a form on my website so users can make a subdomain for their game server so like if the ip for the server is 
192.168.1.132 then they put it into a form and they make a name for the subdomain
and then they can use this to join their server name.domain.com:76651

Comment: This is what iam talking about https://shockbyte.com/subdomain-creator

Answer (score 0):

I'm Mitch from Shockbyte - and the creator of the subdomain creation tool you linked to.

The subdomain creation tool on Shockbyte uses an API that can be purchased at: https://shockbyte.com/billing/cart.php?a=add&pid=34

This includes the PHP files to add the subdomain creator to your own website. This is the system that Shockbyte uses, as well as pretty much every host that has a subdomain creator tool on their website.

If you wish to create your own tool with PHP instead of using the system above, you will need more than just a PHP script.

You will need to be running a DNS server to create the records on. The most popular is probably BIND.

Once you have a DNS server running, then you can write a PHP script to manipulate the records. It will depend on which DNS server you use, but there may be an API available or if you're using a database such as MySQL, then you may be able to directly query the database.